# Ignorar colunas no filtro de pesquisa do datatables.net

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-datatables

Olá, gostaria que quando eu digitar no campo de pesquisa (Search - em Vermelho) ele desconsidere algumas colunas na pesquisa(em azul), olhei a documentação mas não consegui achar nada do tipo, alguém sabe me dizer se tem como?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
um exemplo o porque preciso disso, imagine uma Tabela com Id, nome, Data, unidade e eu for fazer a pesquisa 22, não vai mudar nd pois na coluna Data tem o 2022, ou seja, preciso desconsiderar essa coluna da pesquisa.